# (Using React) Why is the submit button when onClick is performed using onChange events and resulting in empty string? (useState question)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Description:
The submit button calls a function called displayFields.  This function then console logs the state of the input fields.  The start of the input fields is listened to by onChange that sets the new state.

Before clicking the submit button the input fields when something is entered console logs the current state of the fields and then provides each string character in the console.  To my understanding onChange should listen for changes but not console anything.  When the button is clicked it should perform the function one time and console the current state of what is entered in fields.  Instead when clicked the fields clear and then console an empty string.

I will provide my code and screen shots to help.

```
const GetQuote = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");

  const dispFields = () => {
    console.log(name + email + question);
  };

  /*
  This is used in case prevent defualt needs used 
function handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();    }
  */

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form
        id="quoteForm"
        //onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <h1 id="quoteTitle"> Quote Help Form </h1>
        <p id="quotePar">
          {" "}
          Please provide your Name, Contact Email, and what products you would
          like more information about in this form:{" "}
        </p>

        <label id="formName" className="Form">
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setName(event.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </label>

        <label id="formEmail" className="Form">
          Email:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setEmail(event.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label id="formQuestion" className="Form">
          What products would you like to know more about:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="help"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setQuestion(event.target.value);
            }}
          />{" "}
        </label>

        <br />
        <br />

        <button
          id="quoteSubmit"
          type="submit"
          //funtion is called however seems to constantly call the useState which is used in onchange
          //when submit is done returns empty string

          onClick={dispFields()}
        >
          Submit{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Resulting Console]

[image: result when changing onclick function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onClick={dispFields()}` is getting called on every render.  If you pass it without calling it (`onClick={dispFields}` that should only log it to the console when the button is clicked.

Comment: I changed it to onClick={dispFields} per react documentation react doesn't use {function()} it instead uses onClick={example} .  This did change the function being called on every render.  However it also stopped any function being performed.  See screen shot 2 for results of this change :

Answer (score 1):

You try to alter from

```
<
    button id = "quoteSubmit"
    type = "submit"

    //funtion is called however seems to constantly call the useState which is used in onchange
    //when submit is done returns empty string 

    onClick = {
      dispFields()
    } >
    Submit < /button>
```

to

```
<
    button id = "quoteSubmit"
    type = "button"

    //funtion is called however seems to constantly call the useState which is used in onchange
    //when submit is done returns empty string 

    onClick = {()=>
      dispFields()
    } >
    Submit < /button>
```

Changed "button" from "submit", arrow function involved

Comment: That made sense to change. However the result is the form clears as expected and nothing in the console is displayed.  No console errors so it seems to be at least hitting the arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions provided above work.  Changing to example = {example} from example = {example()}.  Also calling it from a arrow function also works.  The issue is a node issue.  What happens when the use breakpoints is set on the function, the values are console logged however after they are console logged the form refreshes and then the state refreshes so the console logs are never logged because the browser processes the value of event and clears the event at the same time.  So as long as the values can be passed to the backend, the front end can remain clearing the value being rendered.

[image]

[image]